# How to convert image.jpg to image.ppm in c++

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, jpeg, ppm

I now hope to convert image.jpg to image.ppm via c++ code implementation. What library can I implement in C++?
By the way: my work platform is Raspberry Pi 3B+.
I look forward to any help and reply from you.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Search for a library for image processing. Open the jpg file and write the image as ppm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [CImg](http://cimg.eu) library for this. It is modern, lightweight and very, very simple to use because it is *"header only"* - just a single include file.

```
#define cimg_display 0  // if you dont have x11.and you can delete-Dcimg_display=0. https://github.com/GreycLab/CImg/issues/187
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace cimg_library;

int main() {
   // Load JPEG image
   CImg<unsigned char> im("image.jpg");

   // Save as PPM
   im.save("result.ppm");
   // show ppm: ffplay -i a.ppm / ffmpeg -i a.ppm a.bmp
}
```

Compile like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -march=native -Dcimg_jpeg=1 -Dcimg_display=0  main.cpp -o main
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion
When I downloaded the .zip file on the Raspberry Pi, I don't know where to put the unzipped files? I used the c++ unofficial library for the first time, so I am not very familiar.

Comment: The only file you need is *"Cimg.h"* which you can put in the same directory as your other C++ source files or in `/usr/local/include` if you plan to use it for many projects. You may need to add `-I .` for the first and `-I /usr/local/include` to your compiler command.

Answer (score 0):

The established **[libjpeg-turbo](https://libjpeg-turbo.org/)** library for fast JPEG image I/O can also read and write the simple PPM image format. You can use `tjSaveImage()` method provided by libjpeg-turbo for that.

In your code, use `tjDecompress2()` and `tjSaveImage()` methods.
See [example code](https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo/blob/master/tjexample.c) in the libjpeg-turbo project.

You might also want to read [this article](http://hopkinsdev.blogspot.com/2016/06/opencv-310-optimized-for-raspberry-pi.html) for how to do an optimized build of OpenCV and libjpeg-turbo on the raspberry platform (do only the `libjpeg-turbo` part).